# How convert data to Json in Realm version 10.15.0

Tags: json, swift, object, realm

in the realm version 10.7.1 it used this code but when migrating to 10.15.0 it is no longer possible because the ListBase class no longer exists

```
extension Object {
    func toWebServiceRequest() -> [String:AnyObject] {
        let properties = self.objectSchema.properties.map { $0.name }
        var dicProps = [String:AnyObject]()
        for (key, value) in self.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: properties) {
            if let value = value as? ListBase {
                dicProps[key] = value.toArray() as AnyObject
            } else if let value = value as? Object {
                dicProps[key] = value.toWebServiceRequest() as AnyObject
            } else {
                dicProps[key] = value as AnyObject
            }
        }
        return dicProps
    }
}
```

```
extension ListBase {
    func toArray() -> [AnyObject] {
        var _toArray = [AnyObject]()
        for i in 0..<self._rlmArray.count {
            let obj = unsafeBitCast(self._rlmArray[i], to: Object.self)
            _toArray.append(obj.toWebServiceRequest() as AnyObject)
        }
        return _toArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mongo team wants you to use the `Codable` protocol rather than some custom encoding mechanism. This is really the proper way to do it, otherwise you have to rely on `Realm` implementation details.

```
class Parent: Object, Codable {
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var children: List<Child>

    convenience init(name: String, children: [Child] = []) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.children.append(objectsIn: children)
    }
}
```

If the server is expecting keys different from your object's property names you can define custom CodingKeys:

```
class Child: Object, Codable {
    @Persisted var id: Int = 0
    @Persisted var name: String = ""

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case name = "name"
    }

    convenience init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
func makeParent() -> Parent {
    Parent(name: "Alex", children: [
        Child(id: 1, name: "Jim"),
        Child(id: 2, name: "Tom"),
        Child(id: 3, name: "Sam"),
        Child(id: 4, name: "Joe"),
    ])
}

func encode<Item: Encodable>(_ item: Item) throws -> Data {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    return try encoder.encode(item)
}

func convertDataToString(_ data: Data) throws -> String? {
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}

func decode<Item: Decodable>(_ type: Item.Type, from data: Data) throws -> Item {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
}

func executeProgram() throws {
    let parent = makeParent()
    let encodedJSONData = try encode(parent)

    guard let encodedJSONString = try convertDataToString(encodedJSONData) else {
        throw Error.badJSON
    }

    print("JSON: \(encodedJSONString)")

    let decodedParent = try decode(Parent.self, from: encodedJSONData)

    print("Decoded Parent: \(decodedParent)")
}
```

On the encode route this results in:

> JSON:
> {"name":"Alex","children":[{"_id":1,"name":"Jim"},{"_id":2,"name":"Tom"},{"_id":3,"name":"Sam"},{"_id":4,"name":"Joe"}]}

And on the decode route this results in:

> Decoded Parent: Parent {  name = Alex;    children = List
> <0x600000a2b800> (        [0] Child {             id = 1;             name = Jim;         },      [1]
> Child {           id = 2;             name = Tom;         },      [2] Child {             id = 3;
> name = Sam;         },      [3] Child {             id = 4;             name = Joe;         }   ); }

You can obviously omit the `String` conversion just work with the resulting `Data`.